# When will a summon/monster step on a trap?

Tags: gloomhaven

Follow-up question to [Which monster does the summon focus on? Long way around, avoiding traps, or get stuck behind a player?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47855/which-monster-does-the-summon-focus-on-long-way-around-avoiding-traps-or-get).

[image]

If I replace the first player on Path 3 with a trap... would the summon then focus on Bones 9 and take Path 2? My assumption is yes.

If I replace the first player on Path 3 with a trap AND put a trap on Path 2... would the summon then focus on Bones 6 and take Path 1? (getting stuck behind that player?)

Or would the summon focus on Bones 9 and take Path 3 stepping on the trap because all of the paths that could actually reach a hex from which to attack go through traps and so it has no other choice and takes the shortest path through a trap? If it does decide to walk through the trap and that trap would do enough damage to kill the summon, would it kill itself or would it go for Asimov's 3rd law and preserve itself?

Answer (score 5):

Following https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47856/20168.

For the first scenario:

Focus: Living Bones 9 
Target Hex: The hex between the door and Living Bones 9. 
Path: Path 2

The reason for this is that monsters/summons will treat traps/hazardous terrain as obstacles unless there is no other path. See the answer in https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47856/20168 for more details.

If there was a trap on path 2, then the summon would take path 4 and step on the trap (assuming it had enough movement to do so). This happens regardless of whether the trap would kill the summon or not. I.E.

Focus: Living Bones 6 
Target Hex: The empty hex adjacent to Living Bones 6 and Living Corpse 8. 
Path: Path 4

Comment: See Questions 4, 5 and 7 [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/234575/gloomhaven-rules-quiz).

Comment: In addition, monsters will not move if the space they started in and the space they would end in are the same number of hexes away from the target.

When monsters move, they will move in such a way that they can get the most out of their attack. For example, if Living Bones wants to attack 2 or more targets and only 1 target is in range, if it is also moving that turn, it will try to be in range of the maximum number of targets that it can.

Comment: @Shankensteinium, Re "*monsters will not move if the space they started in and the space they would end in are the same number of hexes away from the target.*", 1) This is not relevant here. 2) It's not (quite) true. Your very own second point shows a scenario where it could move without getting closer to the monster it targets. The actual rule is that every step of movement must bring it closer to the hex it targets.

Comment: @Shankensteinium, Re "*it will try to be in range of the maximum number of targets that it can*", 1) This is not relevant here. 2) It's not (quite) true. It will try to maximize the number of targets *while keeping its primary focus one of the targets*. This means that it won't move out of range of its primary focus so it can attack 2 (other) targets.

Comment: Tangential but unless I misread, the pdf quiz from the linked post says the walking on trap rule only applies to melee not ranged.  Which I thought was interesting e.g. I would have wondered if I had read this Q&A (I haven't checked citations on any of it).

Comment: @joedragons, That's not true. The rule for traps and hazardous terrain hexes doesn't care whether the attack is melee or ranged. Is it Q7 that confuses you? Given an infinite movement, the archer can attack the Spellweaver without setting off the trap, but not the Cragheart. So the archer will focus on the Spellweaver

Comment: @ikegami Yes thanks, that was my confusion I believe.

Comment: In scenario 2, the first player on path 2 is replaced with a trap also. So it could attack Bones 9 using 2 movement points landing on a trap or it could attack Bones 6 using 4 movement points and also moving over a trap. Shouldn't it go with the one that takes less movement points?